# Android can`t get images from api with picasso

Tags: android, listview, retrofit, picasso

I'm trying to get a picture of the api and put them in a list , but when I`m write picasso, Picasso.with field (context) context emphasizes the red line , I do not where it should be ? Tell me please.

Adapter:

```
 class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Places> {


    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Places> objects) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item, objects);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        View rowView = convertView;
        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.nameOfPlace = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.name_Id);
            holder.subcategory_name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.subcategory_Id);
            holder.geometryName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.geometry_Id);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            holder.imageView2 = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            holder.rating = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.rating_Id);
            rowView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }

        Places places = getItem(position);
        holder.nameOfPlace.setText(places.getName());
        holder.subcategory_name.setText(places.getSubcategory_name());
        holder.geometryName.setText(places.getGeometry_name());

        holder.imageView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.love_5033);
        holder.rating.setText("Рейтинг: " + places.getRating() + "              В избранном: " + places.getFavorite());

 //There is Picasso
        Picasso.with(context).load(places.getCsv_image()) .into(holder.imageView);



        return rowView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {

        public TextView nameOfPlace;
        public TextView subcategory_name;
        public TextView geometryName;
        public TextView rating;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public ImageView imageView2;
    }
}
```

Places class:

```
    public class Places implements Serializable {


    String name;
    String geometry_name;
    String rating;
    String subcategory_name;
    String favorite;
    String csv_image;

    public Places(String name, String geometry_name, String rating,String subcategory_name, String favorite,String csv_image) {
        this.name = name;
        this.geometry_name = geometry_name;
        this.rating = rating;
        this.subcategory_name = subcategory_name;
        this.favorite = favorite;
        this.csv_image = csv_image;

    }



    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String getGeometry_name() {
        return geometry_name;
    }

    public void setGeometry_name(String geometry_name) {
        this.geometry_name = geometry_name;
    }

    public String getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(String rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public String getSubcategory_name() {
        return subcategory_name;
    }

    public void setSubcategory_name(String subcategory_name) {
        this.subcategory_name = subcategory_name;
    }

    public String getFavorite() {
        return favorite;
    }

    public void setFavorite(String favorite) {
        this.favorite = favorite;
    }

    public String getCsv_image() {
        return csv_image;
    }

    public void setCsv_image(String csv_image) {
        this.csv_image = csv_image;
    }
}
```

Initalize adapter, in success of retrofit:

```
  Retrofit.getPlaces(new Callback<List<Places>>() {
        @Override
        public void success(final List<Places> places, Response response) {


            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                fos = openFileOutput("countries_file", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                oos.writeObject(places);
                oos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, places));
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Intent mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapActivity.class);
                    Places plasez = places.get(position);
                    mIntent.putExtra("key", plasez);
                    startActivity(mIntent);
                }
            });


        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



        }
    });




}
```

Full MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

ListView listView;

TextView name;
TextView subcategory_name;
TextView geometry_name;
TextView rating;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_Id);
    subcategory_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.subcategory_Id);
    geometry_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.geometry_Id);
    rating = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rating_Id);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listVieww);




    FileInputStream fis;
    try {
        fis = openFileInput("countries_file");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        final ArrayList<Places> returnlist = (ArrayList<Places>) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
        listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, returnlist));
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapActivity.class);
                Places placez = returnlist.get(position);
                mIntent.putExtra("key", placez);
                startActivity(mIntent);

            }
        });
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }





    Retrofit.getPlaces(new Callback<List<Places>>() {
        @Override
        public void success(final List<Places> places, Response response) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "получили данные");

            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                fos = openFileOutput("countries_file", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                oos.writeObject(places);
                oos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, places));
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Intent mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapActivity.class);
                    Places plasez = places.get(position);
                    mIntent.putExtra("key", plasez);
                    startActivity(mIntent);
                }
            });


        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



        }
    });




}




class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Places> {
    private Context context;




    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Places> objects) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item, objects);


    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        View rowView = convertView;
        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.nameOfPlace = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.name_Id);
            holder.subcategory_name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.subcategory_Id);
            holder.geometryName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.geometry_Id);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            holder.imageView2 = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            holder.rating = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.rating_Id);
            rowView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }

        Places places = getItem(position);
        holder.nameOfPlace.setText(places.getName());
        holder.subcategory_name.setText(places.getSubcategory_name());
        holder.geometryName.setText(places.getGeometry_name());

        holder.imageView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.love_5033);
        holder.rating.setText("Рейтинг: " + places.getRating() + "              В избранном: " + places.getFavorite());
        Picasso.with(context).load(places.getCsv_image()) .into(holder.imageView);


        return rowView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {

        public TextView nameOfPlace;
        public TextView subcategory_name;
        public TextView geometryName;
        public TextView rating;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public ImageView imageView2;

    }
 }

}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? where u have initialized field 'context'?

Comment: Please pass activity context to adapter if you uses activity and if you uses fragment then pass getActivity().getApplicationContext() to adapter and then use that context in adapter in picasso

Comment: Picasso.with field (context) context emphasizes the red line, and i have an exeption context is must be not null

Comment: i am use activity, how to do it?

Comment: You haven't initialized the field 'context' used in that line. Looks like its null .

Comment: please tell me what should I do ?

Comment: @Azarnoy post where u have intialized the adapter?

Comment: in success of retrofit, edited

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private Context context;

public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Places> objects) {
super(context, R.layout.list_item, objects);
this.context = context;}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    View rowView = convertView;
    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.nameOfPlace = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.name_Id);
        holder.subcategory_name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.subcategory_Id);
        holder.geometryName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.geometry_Id);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        holder.imageView2 = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        holder.rating = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.rating_Id);
        rowView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    }

    Places places = getItem(position);
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(places.getCsv_image())) {
            Picasso.with(context).into(holder.imageView)
                    .load(places.getCsv_image());}

    return rowView;
}
```

Comment: compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0' add in  gradle app file

Comment: i added, cant find into just in your example

Comment: Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(places.getCsv_image())
                    .into(holder.imageView);

Comment: Have an exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Context must not be null.

Comment: have you follow all code? I have written above. I think you are not Initialise this.context = context;

Comment: I'm talking about class MyAdapter 
In the class you add this line this.context = context; after super line.

Comment: oh sorry , I did not see it , now works , thank you from the heart!

Comment: You should be using the latest version i.e. 2.5.2

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Context context;

public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Places> objects) {
   super(context, R.layout.list_item, objects);
   this.context = context;
}

...
```

Comment: Have an exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Context must not be null.

Comment: @Azarnoy Show your complete code of MainAcitvity if possible.

Comment: @Azarnoy did u change your adapter class..? That is what u have posted or its partially implemented one.? Because I see you missed a line in constructor. 'this.context = context' in that adapter.?

Comment: i dont change anything, its copypast of my activity

Comment: @Azarnoy I'm talking about your MyAdapter. Please tell me have u changed your MyAdapter class with the suggested answer here.?

Comment: just write private Context context; and all

Comment: Can u add this.context = context;
 line in MyAdapter constructor after super.(...) line.?

Answer (score 0):

Write as below:

```
class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Places> {

Context context=null;


public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Places> objects) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item, objects);
    this.context=context;
}
```

Comment: Have an exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Context must not be null.

Comment: Its because you are sending null from where you are initializing your adapter.Show your code where you are initializing and setting your adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Context context = holder.imageView.getContext();
    String st = android.get(position).getImage();
    String image = st.replace("\\", "");
    if (image.equals("")) {

        Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.profilepi).into(holder.imageView);
    } else {

        Picasso.with(context).load("http://ec2-54-187-18-119.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/lived2d/" + image).resize(100, 100).centerCrop().into(holder.imageView);
    }

}
```

Initialise context in the beginning

Comment: i have that exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must not be empty.

Comment: you are getting this error in which line? The context one or in Picasso one?